# Search for a value in another sheet and copy row if match?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

This is my sample spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ropciT6djExmDh73GO__rNNg1Ny3FlN-Qwzkm1Yan7A/edit?usp=sharing

It has three sheets:

1. Accounts: list of account for Facebook (it's just a random example)
2. Reviews: list of accounts that has already posted a review on Facebook
3. Pivot table

How can I get a list of accounts IDs that has not posted a reviews on Facebook? I can't figure it out. I know I can get a list of accounts that have posted, as you can see on the spreadsheet, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you require but could be a bit long for a comment. If you want to know which entries in Accounts ColumnA do not appear in Reviews ColumnA then a formula such as:

```
=ArrayFormula(match(A2:A45;Reviews!A:A;0))
```

in D2 of Accounts should identify those with `#N/A`. These might then be selected with a query such as:

```
=query(Accounts!A1:D45;"select * where D <0 ")
```

Comment: Thanks! It works pretty well. Just a little extra question... Do you think I could filter results so I get which entries in Accounts Column do not appear in Reviews ColumnA by filtering by Reviews ColumD and ColumnB?

I want to know which Facebook accounts (ColumnB in Reviews) haven't been  used by clien1 (ColumD in Reviews). Thank you.